# Why does Stokes' Theorem allow any surface to be used when calculating a line integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to understand Stokes' Theorem, what I don't get is how it allows you to pick ***any*** surface as long as the boundary is the same.

Let's say that the vector field is increasing in strength along the z-axis, wouldn't then the curl be stronger if you chose a parabola shaped surface with a non-zero z-value compared to the unit disk where z would be zero?

Comment: Are you asking for a proof of the theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a field with increasing strength along the $z$-axis, this means that there must be a *horizontal* component of the curl. This horizontal component will get picked up by the surface integral of the non-horizontal parts of your paraboloid, and that cancels out the fact that the curl at the *top* of the paraboloid is stronger than at a flat surface.

Answer (score 3):

You might think of it this way: the field in question--the one we integrate along the surface--isn't just any field; It's the curl of a given field. As such, it has the nice property of having zero divergence, hence zero 'sources' in the interior of any given closed surface. So that the integrals along any given surface with the same boundary agree is a straightforward result of the divergence theorem.

(of course, there's nothing intrinsically different between the divergence theorem and the Kelvin-Stokes theorem--both are cases of the general Stokes theorem--so perhaps this doesn't help.)